# How can a DBMS_JOB mark itself as broken?

Tags: oracle, scheduling, jobs

I want to run an update on a large list of rows in batches of 1000 rows. When putting the update statement inside some periodically executed DBMS_JOB is there a way for the job to suspend itself after the number of affected rows becomes zero?

Can a job find out its own job ID so it can call `DBMS_JOB.Broken()`?

Comment: do you just want the job to end - then start again on the next scheduled time?

Comment: @Randy: No, I want the job to not be scheduled again.

Comment: Why don't you simply reverse your logic: create only a single job instance, and at the end of the procedure, if there are more rows to process, it creates another job to do the next batch. If there are no more rows, it simply stops.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select JOB from all_jobs
where what like '%YOUR_JOB_PROCEDURE%';
```

Also, I recommend to use DBMS_SCHEDULER instead of DBMS_JOB, if it is also available in your Oracle version
http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14258/d_sched.htm

Comment: If I put some kind of GUID string constant inside the PL/SQL code of my job this should work.

Answer (score 2):

JOB ID is JOB column:

```
select * from dba_jobs
```

Current running jobs:

```
select dbr.sid, s.serial#, s.username, dbj.* 
from dba_jobs_running dbr, dba_jobs dbj , v$session s 
where dbr.job=dbj.job and s.sid=dbr.sid;
```

Comment: And to find out which row corresponds to my current job?